# Bootstrap dropdown doesnt work after ajax call (even after reinitializing)

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I scanned through stackoverflow and understood that its neccessary to refresh the dropdown on an ajax .load()...however not sure how this is working because after clicking the dropdown twice or thrice it stops again.. :/

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ios").click(function(){
        $("#maincontent").load("ios.html",function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
        });
    });
});
```

**html**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Smart Phones <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li ><a href="#" id="android">Android</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="ios">IOS</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="win">Windows</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: Nice to see the word 'Thrice' being used.

Comment: Not sure. Does it fail after two clicks or three clicks? Or does it vary?

Comment: if i click on a single link its twice but if i keep swiching between the links it increases

Comment: It would probably help if you posted some HTML

Comment: i have such jquery function for each id  can i do it in a better way... using a single function ?

Comment: @PushkarKhedekar better a single function

Comment: can u help me out with it ?

Comment: is it possible to create a fiddle (f.ex using bootply) to demonstrate the problem ?

Comment: @DTH i am unable to create a fiddle for it.. messing up the sources..

Comment: What if you edit this snippet to reflect your problem: http://www.bootply.com/NMesgT6OjX

Answer (score 1):

This is about one-year old question but I have the similar trouble and could figure it out. So I will share what I learned after several hours searching. 
One important fact is that **jquery should be included before bootstrap. The order matters.**
Here are what I tested.

My index.html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest jQuery Core Javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrp CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery AJAX call -->
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                           $('#navigation').load('/includes/nav_menu2.html');
            });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navigation"></div>

    Test is working!!!

</body>
</html>
```

1. Notice that jquery javascript and, bootstrap css and javascript are included in head tagg. The order is very important as I said before.
2. jQuery AJAX call included in head tag and load() statement is used to call navigation menu, nav_menu2.html.

My nav_menu2.html is

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">  
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Homepage</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CLASS<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calculus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>                                
                        <li><a href="#">Orchestra</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                           
                <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SPORTS<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Swimming</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Baseball</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Finally, I put the code

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

in body tag. I tested and it worked.